# Need help on Pi Calculation with single multiServer - (N)Clients programm on Java. (Sockets)

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client-server

I am trying to make a single mutlithreaded Server , that many clients can connect. Every client takes his iD and a number of steps and tries to calculate Pi =3,14 with accuracy, after that every client sends its result back to Server and the Server Calculates the Final result finnaly prints Pi.
(Every Client works at the same time).
(We know from start how many Clients will connect)

So far I created the main Server , the ServerThread , and a ServerProtocol where every action is written there. A loop helps that many clients can connect. I gave as a string the specific number of client and the numSteps it has to calculate pi.

On the client side, I made the main Client and the ClientProtocol with the actions. So , the client take the string, make it integer and start calculating pi. At the end sends the result as a string and the Server makes it Integer and put it on an Array to calculate and print 3.14 .

So i am somewhere lost and can't find where , so any help will be aprecciated.

**Server**

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class ServerTCP {

    private static final int PORT = 1234;
    public static String num;
    public static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public static int clientsSoFar=-1;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        // server is listening on port
        ServerSocket connectionSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        System.out.println("Server is listening to port: " + PORT);

         // running infinite loop for getting client request 
        while(true) {

            //Wait for connection and produce actual socket
            Socket dataSocket = null;
             // socket object to receive incoming client requests 
            dataSocket=connectionSocket.accept();
            clientsSoFar++;
            System.out.println("Received request from " + dataSocket.getInetAddress());

            //Server Thread
            ServerTCPThread sthread = new ServerTCPThread(dataSocket);
            sthread.start();
        }

    }

}
```

**ServerThread**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ServerTCPThread extends Thread{

    public static int clientsSoFar;

     private Socket dataSocket;
     private InputStream is;
     private BufferedReader in;
     private OutputStream os;
     private PrintWriter out;
     private static final String EXIT = "!";

     public ServerTCPThread(Socket socket)
     {
         dataSocket = socket;
         try {
             is = dataSocket.getInputStream();
             in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
             os = dataSocket.getOutputStream();
             out = new PrintWriter(os,true);
         }
         catch(IOException e) {
             System.out.println("I/O Error " + e);
         }
     }

     public void run() {

            int clientsP =2;
            int numSteps=100;
            String p = "2 100";

         String inmsg, outmsg;

         try {


                //epeksergasia
                String num1 = String.valueOf(ServerTCP.clientsSoFar);
                String num2 = String.valueOf(numSteps/clientsP);
                ServerTCP.num =num1+" "+num2;

                //epeksergasia
                int numClient;
                String[] splited = p.split("\\s+");
                numClient=Integer.parseInt(splited[0]);

                ServerTcpProtocol app = new ServerTcpProtocol();
                outmsg = app.message();
                out.println(outmsg);

             inmsg = in.readLine();
             outmsg = app.processRequest(inmsg);

            // while(!EXIT.equals(inmsg)) {
                // outmsg = app.processRequest(inmsg);
                 //out.println(outmsg);
                 //inmsg = in.readLine();
            // }
             double outMsgDouble = Double.parseDouble(outmsg);


                double [] pin = new double[clientsP];
                Arrays.fill(pin, 0);

                ServerTCP.lock.lock();
                for (int i=0; i<clientsP; i++)
                    if (pin[i]==0)
                        pin[i]=outMsgDouble;

                ServerTCP.lock.unlock();


             dataSocket.close();
         }
         catch (IOException e) {
             System.out.println("I/O Error --> " + e);
         }
     }

}
```

**ServerProtocol**

```
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ServerTcpProtocol {
    public String processRequest(String theInput) {
        System.out.println("Received message from client: " + theInput);
        String theOutput = theInput;
        //System.out.println("Send message to client: " + theOutput);
        return theOutput;
    }


BufferedReader user = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    public String message() throws IOException {

            System.out.println("Send number to Client: "+ ServerTCP.num);
        //String theOutput = user.readLine();
        String theOutput=ServerTCP.num;

        //SimpleServerTCP.p="+1";
        return theOutput;
        }
}
```

**Client**

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class ClientTCP {

    //Client should know servers address/name
    private static final String HOST = "localhost";
    private static final int PORT = 1234;
    private static final String EXIT = "!";

    public static double sum;
    public static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {
        //Try to connect to server
        Socket dataSocket = new Socket(HOST, PORT);

        //Set up input and output streams
        InputStream is = dataSocket.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        OutputStream os = dataSocket.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(os, true);
        System.out.println("Connection to " + HOST + " established.");

        //Send request and then receive and process reply
        String inmsg, outmsg;
        ClientTcpProtocol app = new ClientTcpProtocol();

        inmsg = in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Time to send back to Server");

        outmsg = app.answere(inmsg);
        out.println(outmsg);


        //Socket close
        dataSocket.close();
        System.out.println("Data Socket closed.");

     }

}
```

**ClientProtocol**

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ClientTcpProtocol {
    BufferedReader user = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    //Request comes from user input
    public String prepareRequest() throws IOException {

        System.out.print("Enter message to send to server:");
    String theOutput = user.readLine();
    return theOutput;
    }

    //Reply goes to user screen
    public void processReply(String theInput) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Message received from server: " + theInput);
    }

    public String answere(String theInput) {
        System.out.println("Received message from Server: " + theInput);
        //String theOutput = theInput;


        int myId;
        double result=0;
        int myStart=1;
        int myStop;
        int numStep;
        double  table= 0;
        int numStep0;
        int numStep1;
        int numStep2;
        int numStep3;
        int numStep4;

         //Input split
         String[] splited = theInput.split("\\s+");
         myId = Integer.parseInt(splited[0]);
         numStep=Integer.parseInt(splited[1]);


         myStop=numStep;

            double step = 1.0 / (double)numStep;
            ClientTCP.lock.lock();
                try {
                    for(int i = myStart; i < myStop; i++) {
                        double x = ((double)i+0.5)*step;
                        table += 4.0/(1.0+x*x);
                     }
           //Maybe this oart should be at the end of Server before calculation???       
                    result = result + ( table * step);

                    String theOutput = Double.toString(result);
                    System.out.println("Send p to Server:" + theOutput);
                    return theOutput;

                 }finally {
                   ClientTCP.lock.unlock();
                 }                              

    }
}
```

Comment: Not the java master ! But I assume the constructor gets called after starting ``ServerTCPThread``. And you are not invoking ``run()`` method from the constructor. Is it ok ?

Comment: @MohithReddy: Calling `start()` on the thread invokes the `run()` method of the class.